# Create patch and apply patch in SmartGit

Tags: git, patch, smartgit

I have a online repository hosted at Bitbucket but one of the developers has Internet connection problems and most of the time can't connect to the repository. In order to mantain the same code at repository and shared between developers I think in create patch and send him trough email. Since him and I use SmartGit client it's possible to create and apply patch from [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/)? I read the [docs](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/documentation/5/show) but didn't find any helpful, any advice on this? I don't know if Git Flow feature is the solution

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This seems to be supported from version 6.5 of SmartGit. 
Here's the changelog: https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/changelog-6.5.x.txt (under SmartGit 6.5 preview 1)

The following steps worked fine for me.

Creating a patch:

1. Open the Log
2. Pick a branch and right-click on a commit
3. Select "Format patch..." and save the file

Applying a patch:

1. Open the Log
2. Go to "Tools" and then "Apply patch..."
3. Select the patch

The patch will be applied on the branch that is currently checked out.

Comment: Some additional information: I have SmartGIT (v7.1.4) on Windows 10 (64 bits) and Xubuntu Linux 16.04 (64 bits), but unfortunately those features are available only on Windows version, although I can't understand why.

Comment: If these, or any, commands are missing, go to preferences, tools & click on "re-add Defaults" - mine were missing, presumably from updates over the years.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like as of SmartGit 22.1 the Format Patch feature is gone again. Thankfully they have it as an example tool on their website: https://docs.syntevo.com/SmartGit/22.1/Example-Tools.html#format-patch

> Save this content to a file `format-patch.yml` and use the *Import* button on the Tools page of the preferences to restore the *Format Patch* feature from SmartGit versions < 22.1.
>
> ```
> tools:
> - name: Format Patch
>   fileStarter: {command: '${git}', parameters: 'format-patch -o "${dirSelect}" -1 ${commit}'}
>   useForOpen: false
>   waitUntilFinished: true
>   filePattern: '*'
> - name: Format Patch
>   fileStarter: {command: '${git}', parameters: 'format-patch -o "${dirSelect}" ${commit}..${commit2}'}
>   useForOpen: false
>   waitUntilFinished: true
>   filePattern: '*'
> ```

Comment: It sais 404 not found. Where do I have to save `format-patch.yml`?

Comment: Updated the link. But in the answer I’m already quoting: “Save this content to a file format-patch.yml and use the Import button on the Tools page of the preferences”. So file locations doesn’t matter, it’s just a means to import the command.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the SmartGit support team whether they implemented `git format-patch` in the GUI or not. I got the following answer:

> No. If it needs a selected commit, it also cannot be worked around
>   using external tools.